# Not sure what this traceback means

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, traceback

So I found this project

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192281/download-song-or-video-from-youtube-using-pytube

online and it allows you to dowload youtube videos from online but when I enter the link and click download it gives me this error and I have no idea what it means and I have tried to search google for the answer but I can't find any solutions so I hope that someone could help me.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\
__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\youtube.py", line 104, in checkYoutubeLink
    self.downloadWindow()
  File "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\youtube.py", line 112, in downloadWindow
    self.app = SecondPage(self.newWindow, self.youtubeEntryVar.get(), self.Folde
rName, self.ChoicesVar.get())
  File "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\youtube.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.yt = YouTube(self.youtubeEntry)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pac
kages\pytube\__main__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.prefetch_init()
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pac
kages\pytube\__main__.py", line 96, in prefetch_init
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pac
kages\pytube\__main__.py", line 170, in prefetch
    age_restricted=self.age_restricted,
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pac
kages\pytube\extract.py", line 121, in video_info_url
    group=0,
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pac
kages\pytube\helpers.py", line 65, in regex_search
    .format(pattern=pattern),
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern (\W[\'"]?t[\'"]?: ?[\'"](.+?)[\
'"]) had zero matches
```

Comment: It seems that the regular expression `\W[\'"]?t[\'"]?: ?[\'"](.+?)[\
'"]` had zero matches and it is needed to proceed with the program. From a user perspective, this could be programmed better.

Comment: @colidyre Do you know how I would fix this?

Comment: @colkat406 The first place I would look is in your file `"C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pac
kages\pytube\helpers.py"`. Specifically on line 65, and maybe see how the script is using it. There should be documentation in the `regex_search` section of what it is doing...Assuming the creator was forward thinking enough to include it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this error was coming from pytube, I did a quick search of their issues in github. This is the issue for the problem:

https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/381

It says it is fixed in version 9.5.0, `pip install -U pytube` should install the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

`traceback` is the sequence of unreturned-from calls made up until the point where the actual error occurred.  It helps you identify not only the specific error, but the context in which it occurred.